# Por que me sale a consola en blanco

Tags: c, eclipse

Estoy intentado crear este programa en Ecipse con C.

Lo que quiero que haga es cuando se ingrese un código(int) si no se ha ingresado ya, que te pida el precio, caso contrario que aparezca un mensaje que diga "Código ya registrado", así hasta que el usuario ingrese 0(finalizará el programa).
Cuando finalice el programa deberá mostrar la media, el producto más caro, más barato, el código del mismo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const float PUNTOSxEURO = 0.25;
int main() {

    int producto, producto_max, n = 0;
    float precio, precio_max = 0, precio_min, total = 0, media = 0;

    printf("Ingrese un codigo:\n");
    scanf("%i", &producto);

    while (producto > 0) {
        scanf("%f", &precio);
        total += precio;

        if (precio > precio_max) {
            precio_max = precio;
            producto_max = producto;
        }

        if (precio < precio_min) {
            precio_min = precio;
        }

        n++;
        scanf("%d", &producto);
    }

    media = total / n;

    printf("El importe total de la compra en euros es: %.2f\n", total);
    printf("La media en importe de los productos de la compra es: %.2f\n",
            media);
    printf("El código del producto más caro es: %d\n", producto_max);
    printf("El precio del producto más caro es: %.2f\n", precio_max);
    printf("El precio del producto más barato es: %.2f\n", precio_min);
    printf("La cantidad de puntos acumulados por la compra es: %.2f\n",
            PUNTOSxEURO * total);
    return 0;
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me sale la consola en blanco y no me aparece el texto del printf  **printf("Ingrese un codigo:\n");** y cuando ingreso en numero 0 que es el indidicador de que el programa finalizó, aparece la consola asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recién estoy aprendiendo este lenguaje, así que no se si es debido a la configuración al ejecutar o por que no estoy interpretando de manera correcta el programa.

La configuración de run la tengo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente se te olvidó volver a imprimirlo.

```
while (producto > 0) {
    scanf("%f", &precio);
    total += precio;

    if (precio > precio_max) {
        precio_max = precio;
        producto_max = producto;
    }

    if (precio < precio_min) {
        precio_min = precio;
    }

    n++;
    printf("Ingrese un código:\n"); // Te faltó esta línea 
    scanf("%d", &producto); // Aquí vuelves a pedir un producto
}
```

Comment: Pero al ejecutar el programa por primera vez, me debería salir este mensaje en la consola printf("Ingrese un codigo:\n"); pero no me sale nada solo espera a recibir datos.

Comment: @Rosa a caso borraste todo lo que está fuera del while?

Comment: https://tio.run/##jZRLTsMwEIb3OcWoCNTSUNJIbFpgxwIJUcRjh4SM7RRLiR05jqiEehjOwBF6sGDHNnFfqFkk8eifb8b/OMFnc4yb5ohxnNeEwmWlCBOjj@sIC14pyHKBFDy83D/PnhY3L48zuIJklF5MI8YVFIjx/gC@ItCXCZRSkBorEf@9vRVoEQM3adNWZomlpJi1MvM0IqPo1ozHoIRCuQ0XlDBkGS2klLpa1u/d8rmkFYWaAxaEzcXklfcGtlCFEdeSY9aL4cS3M3CAzw@WU@j7MFxD4vcR5mY21/TkqOayjQ2vXLcO2XqQGaYJamK3txBt2w927SHrgs69VmKXnWi5s@Zl4N@@mozvqBng@HDYxQ/xOfSLbHgdsP0IrXnnwDdGeZMDK0ohFXUSfRpzpMsVpURAOdBaigpoNYHjUZrp@u6EuDKec4dcKZ3igQalc31j1QY7RLa5G0jdGl79mG3rxPwPA8XquwKMpLAI0gLC0W1z3KD@w/hOguNzOOYdSaT2gPSZ2LJKz00xgohxpKy58QbhuqhzRIxhQu7zKfwlnK4NQlJVS24@1WXTjKNxkkRplOp78gs

Comment: no, no lo he borrado, lo tengo tal cuál lo he puesto aquí.